# Call web service in android 4.1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code here that worked all this time in 2.3 now we have to update it and I am getting a lot of errors like `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I want to go and grab a xml from my web service, bring it down and parse it into an array list. Here is the code

```
//Gets the xml from the url specified
String CallWebService(String url){
        String xml = null;
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
}
//Parses the xml to get DOM element 
public Document GetDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            //Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            //Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
            // return DOM
        return doc;
}
//Gets the child nodes of the xml
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
 }
```

I also have a `getChildElements` method. The problem is when I call this method. I used to do so like this:

```
String serviceURL = "http://webservice.example.com/";
String xml = CallWebService(serviceURL);
Document doc = GetDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
getChildElements(nl);
```

But now in 4.1 I need to do this asynchronously and I don't know how. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is what i have bu the Thread does not start

```
final String serviceURL = "urlString";
mHandler = new Handler() {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {                             
     if(msg.what == JOB_COMPLETE) {
       String xml = (String) msg.obj;
       Document doc = GetDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

       NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
       getChildElements(nl); 
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);
  }
};

Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       String xml = CallWebService(serviceURL);
       Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, JOB_COMPLETE, xml);
       msg.sendToTarget();
  }
};                                              
t.start();
```

**EDIT**

So I am trying the async way and it still wont work. Its not hitting the GetDomElement at all. Here is the code.

```
   //I call this in my onCreate()
   new getAppInfo().execute("http://webservice.example.com");

   private class getAppInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return CallWebService(urls[0]);
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {
        Document doc = GetDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
        getChildElements(nl); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement an AsyncTask:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Btw this is needed from Android 3 (if I remember well).

I've implemented this in my app, you can browse my code here: https://github.com/enrichman/roma-tre/blob/master/src/com/roma3/infovideo/utility/rss/RssTask.java

Comment: So do I just encapsulate my three methods in an method that extends async and keep the way I call it the same?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Should work. The AsyncTask are necessary to avoid blocking operation to the UI. Just call in your main class the execute method.

Comment: Actually you have to implement a new class that extend AsyncTask with his methods.

Comment: Check the above code. This is in my main activity. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Is the CallWebServer method called correctly? After the execution of that method it will deliver the result to the onPostExecute()

Comment: Try to pass to the getAppInfo the activity like: `new getAppInfo(this).execute("...");` and then use a private field inside the getAppInfo class to get the Activity. In this way you're able to "store" the childElements somewhere. Btw you're calling it right. Have you tried to debug and see what's happening?

Comment: I have tried adding `(this)` but I am getting an error. Ill keep working with it. When I debug it goes into the `doBackground` but it doesn't go into `onPostExecute`

Comment: The reason it is not running is because it is in my onClick method. How can it be called inside an onClick?

Comment: Hm, I suppose yes. Just add a constructor to the class like `public getAppInfo(Activity activity) {this.activity = activity}`. Keep debugging and let me know. If it doesn't reach the onPostExecute seems like it's not getting the xml file.

Comment: So after working on it I have it working but When I call the `getChildElements(nl)` and it goes through the values aren't being stored in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Handler in your main ui thread in activity onCreate for example

```
private Handler mHandler;
private static int JOB_COMPLETE = 1;   

mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == JOB_COMPLETE) {
            String xml = (String) msg.obj;
            // do whatever you want with that string
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
 };
```

Then run all your long jobs in background thread

```
final String url = "...........";
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String xml = CallWebService(url);
        Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, JOB_COMPLETE, xml);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: where does that `t.start()` go? is that inside the run method?

Comment: start() will run the defined thread's code inside run() { }
so decide when you need to start background job

Comment: You didnt show where do you call this lines 

`String serviceURL = "http://webservice.example.com/";`
`String xml = CallWebService(serviceURL);`

so I dont know where you should run the thread...

Comment: Looks correct. Wonder why it might not work. Did you try to debug? Try to place breakpoint on `t.start()` and on first line inside `run()`

Comment: Yes and it goes to the t.start() and just skips over it